# Xamarin Forms Debugging Command Bindings

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using the `Corcav.Behaviors` and I've done quite a few changes, and obviously I've incorrectly changed one of my behavior bindings to a `Command` somehow.

When running the application, it therefore halts and doesn't load the page as there is a binding issue.

The message I get is:-

```
Exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: No command available, Is Command properly set up?
```

And the breakpoint where the exception is thrown is at the BindingContext = ViewModel

Is there a quick way of identifying the failed binding?, rather than manually checking every `{Binding}` in the `XAML` page against the `View Model`, as this seems too long winded to find an individual fault when the fault is really already known, but not shown!??

Thanks,

Comment: Check the output window which will show a lot of command failure errors

Comment: @Krishna Unfortunately the only information in the Debug Output Window is the one I listed above.